# linOTP to openVPN authentication ubuntu 12.04

Tags: ubuntu, openvpn, authentication, ubuntu-12.04, two-factor-authentication

I am working on a project in which I have to install a one-time password authentication. I have successfully installed openVPN to which I can connect without any authentication. I have installed the OTP software linOTP which I have connected to my LDAP server.

The connection to the LDAP server is functioning, and I have assigned a token to a user. When testing the token using the debug interface ://myip:5001/validate/check  it prints the response:

```
{
   "version": "LinOTP 2.8.0.3", 
   "jsonrpc": "2.0", 
   "result": {
      "status": true, 
      "value": true
   }, 
   "id": 0
}
```

Meaning the authentication for linOTP is functioning, however when I enable password authentication on the openVPN server it fails to authenticate.

```
AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: user 'jdoe' failed to authenticate: Authentication failure
```

I have made all configurations according to this guide: https://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-set-up-openvpn-to-authenticate-with-linotp

This is how my client.ovpn looks:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert jdoe.crt
key jdoe.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
auth-user-pass
```

server.conf:

```
port 1194
proto udp
dev tun
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key
dh dh2048.pem
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0"
push "dhcp-option DNS 192.168.0.3"
push "dhcp-option DNS myip"
client-to-client
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
status openvpn-status.log
verb 3
plugin /usr/lib/openvpn/openvpn-auth-pam.so openvpn
```

and linotp files,
common-linotp:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_python.so /lib/security/pam_linotp.py \
    nosslhostnameverify nosslcertverify debug url=https://localhost/validate/check 
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
auth    required            pam_permit.so
```

I will be using self-signed HTTPS certificates so I included nosslhostnameverify and nosslcertverify according to the pam_py_linotp section of this guide: https://www.linotp.org/howtos/howto-openvpn.html

and finally the /etc/pam.d/openvpn file:

```
@include common-linotp 
session    sufficient pam_permit.so
account    sufficient  pam_permit.so
```

I am new to server configuration and would appreciate any help.

The server runs ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: The user fails to authenticate in the PAM stack. So please take a look into /var/log/auth.log.

Comment: Thank you cornelinux! At first it turned out I should not be using https://, and I also needed to add the port number to the debug link, but this in turn gave me a new error. When I then changed the the link to validate with simplecheck instead it worked!

Answer (score 1):

For me this problem was solved by adding **`hide_otp_input`**. This is badly documented, but solved the same problem for me.

I am using the `pam_linotp.so` module, not the python implementation which may make a difference.

Comment: dude you solved my problem   wish that hide_otp_input was better documented